# Display inline or float without breaking - without using media queries

Tags: html, css, inline, display

When I try to add float left or display inline, things break. Currently, I have a max-width of 1000px for the form. What I was hoping is somehow, the first, and last name will automatically float side by side if it is wide enough. So perhaps a min-width for inputs First and Last name?

Important note: I wrote this to test out writing CSS DRY code. You notice if you change the font size, the whole project changes size, So this is important to me. Also, I do **not** want to use media queries.

I am aware that I may need to change my approach, and I am open to that as well. Not so much looking for an exact code answer.

```css
form {
    text-align: center;
}

form ul, form li, form input, form label {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
form ul {
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: .3em;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

form li {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: inherit;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
}

form label {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .3em .3em;
    padding-bottom: .1em;;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

form input, form input:focus {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: inherit;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: .7em .1em;
    padding-bottom: .2em;;
}

form input:focus {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .2);
}

form input[type="submit"] {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 1.8em;
    font-size: .6em;
    height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #ddd;
    
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="first-name" type="text" autofocus>
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="last-name" type="text">
            <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="username" type="text">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </li>
    </ul>
    
</form>
```

Comment: Start with valid HTML and then debug. `ul` may only have `li` elements as children—you've got a `div` and an `input` in there.

Comment: That was actually not supposed to be there anyway... its gone now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is with Flexbox.
Set the parent element to display type 'flex'.
Also set up flex wrap: wrap // This way the children will wrap if needed.
The children become flex objects. Since I want them to be even, I set them both to flex grow: 1
Set the children to flex-basis as 300px. // This is almost like a minimum width. This triggers the wrap.

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
.main {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main input {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.one {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 300px
}

.two {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 300px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inline.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <form class="main">

        <input type="text" class="one">
        <input type="text" class="two">

    </form>
    
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is the most modern solution to this problem. However, remember to add the necessary prefixes for some browsers. If IE9 support is necessary, see the float solution below:

HTML

```
 <form action="">
    <ul>
        <li class="split">
            <input id="first-name" type="text" autofocus>
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
        </li>
        <li class="split">
            <input id="last-name" type="text">
            <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
        </li>
        <li class="fill">
            <input id="username" type="text">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
        </li>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </ul>

</form>
```

CSS

```
form {
    text-align: center;
}

form ul, form li, form input, form label {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
form ul {
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: .3em;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

form li {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: inherit;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
}

form label {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .3em .3em;
    padding-bottom: .1em;;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

form input, form input:focus {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: inherit;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: .7em .1em;
    padding-bottom: .2em;;
}

form input:focus {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .2);
}

form input[type="submit"] {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 1.8em;
    font-size: .6em;
    height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #ddd;

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  li {
    clear: both;
  }

  li.split {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qefo9eLr/

Comment: Flexbox is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I just didnt know what it was called. I will do some study on flexbox. Thank you!

Comment: Though I spoke too soon, is there a way to do this without media queries? Using min width or something like that?

Comment: If you use inline elements you could use min-width (https://jsfiddle.net/qefo9eLr/3/). However, you could end up with issues on mobile devices if min-width exceeds the screen width. Typically, I wouldn't be concerned with using media queries.

Comment: Media queries are fine, but I am expanding my knowledge of CSS and that means creating interesting scenarios such as this one. I found that Flex box with wrap and flex basis works wonders! No media queries needed. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.fl-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use bootstrap grid system

this way u can have the inputs into columns

[bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

look at this fiddle:
[gri system sample](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Gt25L/)

```
<div class='row'>
<div class="col-xs-2">Hi</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">Hi</div>
```

in your case col-xs-6 will give you 2 columns fullwidth

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're going for, but it seems to fit your criteria.

```css
form {
  text-align: center;
}
form ul,
form li,
form input,
form label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
form ul {
  font-size: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: .3em;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
form li {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: inherit;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
}
form label {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  border-bottom-color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .3em .3em;
  padding-bottom: .1em;
  ;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: .6em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
form input,
form input:focus {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
form #fl-name {
  display: inline-block;
}
form .floatMe {
  float: left;
}
form .clearMe {
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <ul>
    <div class="fl-name">
      <li class="floatMe">
        <input id="first-name" type="text" autofocus>
        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
      </li>
      <li class="floatMe clearMe">
        <input id="last-name" type="text">
        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
      </li>
    </div>
    <li>
      <input id="username" type="text">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </ul>

</form>
```

Comment: I appreaciate the response, though this did break the code.  Fllexbox was what I was looking for. I just didn't know the name :)

Comment: @MichaelBruce I'm glad you got it all figured out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative using our old faithful floats: https://jsfiddle.net/mvpu6s5o/3/

The main difference is basically here:

```
form li {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}

form li:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
}

form li:last-child {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

I used a width with percentage to keep it fluid, so it'll adjust to different screen sizes. The `li:nth-child(3)` float the last input to the right, so we can get rid of a small gap at the end due to the 33.33% width. `form li:last-child` is used to clear both floats to the last input (since this too is an li).

Answer (score 0):

I just change the semantic and apply flexbox. This is the result:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  align-items: center;
  /background-color: #EB6361;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}
form {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(204,204,204,.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}
form header {
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
}
form header p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'ubuntu';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
form .body {
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
form .body .block {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
form .body .block:not(first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
form .body .block:first-of-type > .group {
  width: 98%;
}
form .body .block:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
}
form .body .block .group {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
form .body .block:first-of-type .group:first-of-type {
  border-right: 2px solid #333;
}
form input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 22pt;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
form input:focus, form input:focus + label {
  background-color: #F7F8E0;
}
form label {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #bbb;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'ubuntu';
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
form footer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
form footer button {
  background-color: #F39C12;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <header>
    <p>Submit Query Form</p>
  </header>
  <section class="body">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="group">
        <input type="text" />
        <label for="">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="text" />
        <label for="">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="group">
        <input type="text" />
        <label for="">Username</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <button>Submit query</button>
  </footer>
</form>
```